# C# List as delegate for BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, list, delegates, begininvoke

I'm tearing my hair out with this one and I already wasted more than a day on this.  I'm sure it's something stupid and I simply don't have enough experience so any help is much appreciated!

Here's the deal... I have a List of National Instruments Graph objects that I have to refresh with new data.
Does this make sense?  It works with the code below but obviously for just one Graph.
The question is, how to pass the List of Graphs instead of just one and then loop through them to assign data.
Thank you in advance!

```
    private void GetAndPlotData(Action<object> actionPlotData)
    {
        for (int ok = 0; ok < 10000000; ok++)
        {
            // Get some data here for every graph
            double[][] testData = new double[2][];
            testData[0] = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            testData[1] = new double[] { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

            // Plot it
            // QUESTION - how to reference passed List of Graphs in the loop to assign data?
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(actionPlotData, new object[] { testData });

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private async void StartTest()
    {
        // QUESTION -  how to pass List Of Graphs as an Action to loop through them later on?
        await Task.Run(() => GetAndPlotData(data => Graphs[0].DataSource = data));
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: No, the question doesn't really make sense at the moment. There's no "pass list of graphs" - and the use of object is rather less helpful than a minimal but clear example...

Comment: Ok I will update code with what I have instead of "objects".  I just used objects in case someone was going to compile it.  I added questions in code and also updated my description.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand completly the question so here is a first proposal so that you can explain how this is not what you are looking for :)

```
private void GetAndPlotData(List<Action<object>> actionPlotData)
{
    for (int ok = 0; ok < 10000000; ok++)
    {
        // Get some data
        double[][] testData = new double[2][];
        testData[0] = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        testData[1] = new double[] { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

        // Plot it
        // QUESTION - how to reference passed List of Graphs in the loop?
        for (int i = 0; i < actionPlotData.Count; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(actionPlotData[i], new object[] { testData[i] });
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

private async void StartTest()
{
    // QUESTION -  how to pass List Of Graphs as an Action to loop through them later on?
    await Task.Run(() => GetAndPlotData( new List<Action<object>> { 
        data => Graphs[0].DataSource = data,
        data2 => Graphs[1].DataSource = data2
        });
}
```

updated version for dynamic list

```
    var actions = Graphs.Select(g => (Action<object>)(data => g.DataSource = data)).ToList();

    // QUESTION -  how to pass List Of Graphs as an Action to loop through them later on?
    await Task.Run(() => GetAndPlotData(actions));
```

Comment: Yep that does plot in both Graphs so it's a start!  You basically understand it correctly.  But let's say I have 8 or even more Graphs.  Would I literally have to manually write out each one line at a time (when passing)?  Or is there some way to do as one parameter?

Comment: You want the collection in start test to be dynamic not hard coded right?

Comment: Yes.  I'd love to know how to do this because it'd be applicable to many places in my project.  Thanks!

Comment: ok I edited my answer with another version of the start test content. The idea is to build an action from each graph using linq.

Comment: Nice!  Very elegant and makes sense now that I see it. Thank you so much!  I will go ahead and integrate this solution into my code.  Pretty sure it's gonna work.

Comment: Works!  Thank you!